# Print Composer - raster layer name as text field

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I have three Landsat scenes and one polygon shapefile (column "region"). The atlas option is great to create prints of each "region". Is it possible to show the Landsat (raster) layer name automatically as a text field?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably, but I am puzzled, the region you show in the top images is the same for both, but the underlying rasters are different. Are you creating more than one atlas? What is determining which raster is shown?

Comment: I would like to see 2 or maby more LS scenes (zoome to one region) on one sheet of paper. This allows me to compare the different rasters. It would be also nice to see which date time the raster has. This information I'd like to see inside the text box above the picture.

Comment: It's definitely possible, but we'll need more information about your table structures and atlas setup to give a specific answer